# How would you add comments to an arbitrary amount of lines?

Tags: python, regex, string

After inputting a string such as: `'3,11,15,16,35'`
if you wanted each number to represent the line-number of some code,
for the purpose of adding a comment to those lines,
what would you do?

More specifically, in a for-loop where you iterate over each line of code, how would you check the string to see if it contains the current line number.
Here's there relevant section of what I tried:

```
self.num = input('Line(s) to number?')
self.linelist = self.code.splitlines()

for i, element in enumerate(self.linelist):
    self.count += 1
    # if match(str(self.count) + r",", self.num):
    if self.num.find(str(self.count) + ','):
        self.final = self.final + element + ' # line ' + str(self.count) + '\n'
    else:
        self.final = self.final + element + '\n'
```

The `re.match` attempt only comments the first line-number in the string.
The `find` attempt seems to match the first,
*but* comments everything other than the line associated with that number.
The other issue with this setup is that `1,` could be found if `11,` was in the list.

Comment: I tried to simplify it; but I asked too many things, and Avaris expertly answered all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, you are using the result of `find` directly in an `if` statement. Just look at what `find` returns:

> Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such
>   that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure.
>   Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is
>   the same as for slices.

So, you will be getting an `integer` corresponding the index of first match or `-1`. When you do `if an_integer:`, it is actually doing `if bool(an_integer):`. `bool(an_integer)` is `False` for `an_integer==0` and `True` for everything else. That means you'll be doing `else` part if your line number is found at the beginning of the input and `if` part for everything else. You'll need to do something like:

```
if self.num.find(str(self.count) + ',') >= 0:
```

to denote a match.

As for the `re.match` part, `re.match` tries to match a substring *from the beginning of the string*. You should use `re.search` instead.

That being said, even with these fixes and even with the delimiter you'll still have the problem of mismatch as you identified. `11,` will match both `1,` and `11,`. To solve this, you can split the input with delimiter and obtain a list of values. Then you can check if the value is in that list:

```
self.num = input('Line(s) to number?').split(",")
# ...
    if str(self.count) in self.num:
    #...
```

As a small side note, you are already using `enumerate` to get the line numbers. That should eliminate the use of counter (i.e. `self.count`). If you want them to start from `1`, you can tell `enumerate` to do so by giving the optional second argument:

```
for i, element in enumerate(self.list, 1):
```

Then, use `i` instead of `self.count`.

Comment: I appreciate your thorough answer! Everything is clear to me now.